# how to display data from related table in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

i got the problem when to display data from related table using yii2. I use my own design and not using from yii2 design.
I have two tables **user** and **state**

```
TABLE `user`(
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`state_id` int(11) null 

table `state`(
`state_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`state` varchar(225) null
```

**UserModel.php**

```
public function getStates()
{
    return $this->hasOne(State::className(),['state_id' =>'state_id']);
}
```

**UserController.php**

```
 public function actionView($id)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),

    ]);
}
```

**State.php**

```
 public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'state_id' => 'State ID',
        'state' => 'State',
     ];
}

public function getState()
{
    return $this->state.'';
}
```

**view.php**

```
<table>..<tr>
    <td>Negeri</td>
    <td><?php echo $model->states; ?></td>
</tr>
```

when I use $model->states; I got the error when execute at the browser. The error is "**Object of class app\models\State could not be converted to string**". Before I write that code, I use $model->state_id and the result is number value which is state_id attribute from table state. What I want is, the name of the state(state attribute from table state),not the state_id. If using yii2 design, the results will be displayed from what I want. That code its look like this::

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'states.state',

    ],
]) ?>
```

So, my question is how to recall function getStates() from UserModel.php or getState() from state.php that I created to view.php and display data from related table? . sorry, if my english language not very well .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `$model->states` is an object, you should simply use :

```
<?= $model->states->state ?>
```

And you don't need `getState()` function in State model.

Comment: ouh..just like that ? Why I am not a genius like you?..hehe..thanks answer my question.